# Capture javascript output in PHP ob_get_clean()?

Tags: php, output, ob-start, ob-get-contents

I'm trying to allow JS to execute inside PHP's output buffering.

I have tried declaring ob_start and then referencing the javascript, then getting the contents

```
<?php
ob_start(); ?>
<script language="Javascript" src="https://www.ip2phrase.com/j?template=.   <ISP>"></script>
<?php
$visitorISPW = ob_get_clean();
```

I was hoping to get the result of the JS src, which is a document.write.

Instead I get the full results of the script. The end result of the script is just javascript executing again from the source URL.

I would prefer the JS to execute, and then grab the result in PHP.

Comment: This question is not a duplicate, clearly what I'm trying to do is possible. https://sebastiandedeyne.com/server-side-rendering-javascript-from-php/

Comment: What you're trying to do is *possible*, but doing it that way is fairly absurd. You'll be better off just using `file_get_contents('https://www.ip2phrase.com/j?template=%3CISP%3E')` and parsing the response.

Comment: @ceejayoz Perfect thank you!